# Usar a função para comparar valor e marcar radio buttom

Tags: php

Preciso criar uma função para comparar valor e marcar o radio buttom.

```
$checklistIni = unserialize($row_rsRegistros['checklistIni']);
$a = join(',', array_values($checklistIni));

function compara($valor) {
    $array = explode(",", $a);
    if(in_array($valor, $checklistIni)) {
        return "checked";
    }
}
```

E depois usar direto onde preciso fazer a comparação.

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
        <td class="texto-branco">Documento</td>
        <td><label><input value="tem" <?php echo compara("tem"); ?>  name="checklistFim0" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="nao" <?php echo compara("nao"); ?>  name="checklistFim0" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="ava" <?php echo compara("ava"); ?>  name="checklistFim0" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td class="texto-branco"> Manual </td>
        <td><label><input value="tem" <?php echo compara("tem"); ?>  name="checklistFim1" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="nao" <?php echo compara("nao"); ?>  name="checklistFim1" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="ava" <?php echo compara("ava"); ?>  name="checklistFim1" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td class="texto-branco">Vidro eletrico </td>
        <td><label><input value="tem" <?php echo compara("tem"); ?>  name="checklistFim2" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="nao" <?php echo compara("nao"); ?>  name="checklistFim2" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="ava" <?php echo compara("ava"); ?>  name="checklistFim2" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td class="texto-branco">Radio/CD </td>
        <td><label><input value="tem" <?php echo compara("tem"); ?>  name="checklistFim3" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="nao" <?php echo compara("nao"); ?>  name="checklistFim3" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
        <td><label><input value="ava" <?php echo compara("ava"); ?>  name="checklistFim3" class="checklistFim" type="radio" /><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: algo como `echo $key1 . ","`?

Comment: Claro exemplo de problema XY. Não existe justificativa para você partir de um *array*, gerar uma *string*, para depois passar o valor (como variável global?) para uma função que converterá novamente em *array*. A solução parece bem ineficaz e você pode resolver seu problema evitando que aconteça, fazendo de uma forma mais plausível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar o index da listagem do valores que você quer testar para poder comparar. Veja:

```php
$checklistIni = unserialize($row_rsRegistros['checklistIni']);

function compara($array, $index, $valor) {
    if(isset($array[$index] && $array[$index] == $valor)) {
        return "checked";
    }
    return '';
}

// printar o atributo checked SOMENTE se o primeiro item da listagem for "tem"
<input value="tem" <?php echo compara($checklistIni, 0, "tem"); ?> />
```

O exemplo acima parte do princípio que o resultado da função `unserialize` é um array com índices numéricos. Caso o resultado seja um array associativo, basta trocar a declaração da variável `$checklistIni` para:

```php
$checklistIni = array_values(unserialize($row_rsRegistros['checklistIni']));
```

Comment: Olá Vinicius, estou usando a terceira opção, mas não esta marcando. Ou melhor, esta, mas todas da mesma coluna correspondente a ava.

Comment: Editei minha resposta pois havia entendido sua pergunta de forma equivocada,  pois o titulo da sua pergunta não condiz que contexto do que você quer fazer.

Comment: Essa é a minha tela http://prntscr.com/o1yecx

Comment: Deu erro 500 na página

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa e com título que não reflete seu real problema e ainda com contéudo incompleto. Sugiro você dar uma lida em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e após isso editar sua pergunta incluindo o trecho onde você printa o campo checkbox (e não apenas o html do campo direto como está na pergunta) para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Nem uma ultima tentativa? Essa é minha tela https://prnt.sc/o1yecx

Comment: Fiz a edição Vinicius. Veja se consegui explicar melhor, me desculpe, sou péssimo com palavras e expressão.

Comment: Poderia incluir o que está sendo armazenado em `$checklistIni` ?